# Issues in Recyclrview Adapter with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

When I try to click on list of items on First Fragments list it will not go to another fragment.  Can anyone solve this issue?let me know what is the issue in the adapter class?i cant understand what is my issue?

```
String[] text;
String[] text1;
String str;
Context context;
public ExampleAdapter(Context context,String[] text, String[] text1) {
    this.text = text;
    this.text1 = text1;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public ExampleAdapter.ViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.items_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolders(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleAdapter.ViewHolders holder, final int position) {

    holder.moviename.setText(text[position]);
    holder.date.setText(text1[position]);

    holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                android.support.v4.app.Fragment castFragment = new CastFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager =((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.linear,castFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));


    } else {
        holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return  text.length;
}
class ViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView moviename, date;
    LinearLayout layout;
    public ViewHolders(View view) {
        super(view);
        moviename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        layout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
    }
}
```

logactr erros:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          Process:    ctel.animation, PID: 3168
                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
                                                              at ctel.animation.ExampleAdapter$1.onClick(ExampleAdapter.java:48)
                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Post your *Logcat errors* if any.

Comment: once check my post

Comment: You need to pass *context* of your adapter class while doing `Fragment Transaction`.

Comment: i can t undersatnd i am passing context already once post that line of code

Comment: Use context you passed from fragment to your RecyclerAdapter.

Comment: Can you paste your full adapter class?

Comment: i cant understand @M faisal Hyder

Comment: @A.asha : your question is not clear to me.. does the first Fragment contains the RecyclerView? and on click on any list in the RecyclerView do you want to move to the second Fragment (i.e. castFragment)?

Comment: yess that is what i want

Comment: Try to use context.getSupportFragmentManager() instead of casting it with your activity reference.

Comment: no answer is workiing